# After upgrading Ansible to 2.9.9 cannot connect to Windows Hosts, hostname has disappeared from Ansible logs

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, winrm

I recently upgraded Ansible from 2.5.3 to 2.9.9. OS is RHEL 7.5, Python 2.7.

Windows module setup.ps1 cannot fetch the host name of target windows host and hence the playbook unable to connect windows VM, after upgrading to Ansible 2.9.9.

before ESTABLISH WINRM connection log statement you can see that
**<>** is empty. Hence ansible windows connection has stopped working.

```
      Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
    Pipelining is enabled.
    **<>** ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: 7771234s_tskSV on PORT 5985 TO
    creating Kerberos CC at /tmp/tmpn5jvwl
    calling kinit with subprocess for principal 7771234s_tskSV
    Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
    Pipelining is enabled.
    <> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: 7771234s_tskSV on PORT 5985 TO
    creating Kerberos CC at /tmp/tmp0hJgs1
    calling kinit with subprocess for principal 7771234s_tskSV
    kinit succeeded for principal 7771234s_tskSV
    **<> WINRM CONNECT: transport=kerberos endpoint=http://:5985/wsman
    <> WINRM CONNECTION ERROR: Invalid URL u'http://:5985/wsman': No host supplied what to do**
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/winrm.py", line 415, in _winrm_connect
        self.shell_id = protocol.open_shell(codepage=65001)  # UTF-8
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 157, in open_shell
        res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 234, in send_message
        resp = self.transport.send_message(message)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 243, in send_message
        self.build_session()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 232, in build_session
        self.setup_encryption()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 237, in setup_encryption
        prepared_request = self.session.prepare_request(request)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
        hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 305, in prepare
        self.prepare_url(url, params)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 382, in prepare_url
        raise InvalidURL("Invalid URL %r: No host supplied what to do" % url)
    InvalidURL: Invalid URL u'http://:5985/wsman': No host supplied what to do
```

Can you please suggest if the setup.ps1 is not up to date?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit your question and format it correctly so others can actually read it. Thanks

Comment: thanks @Zeitounator , I have tried to re-format my question. Kindly help !!

Comment: You should also provide a sample of the playbook, inventory, and how you're executing the playbook.